# Null pointer exception. cant run my android application

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

Please help me fix my android app. this happens when i run it in the emulator. cant seem to find the answer to these errors.

here is my logcat

```
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.miraapp/com.example.miraapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at com.example.miraapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-10 17:37:56.283: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     ... 11 more
```

here is my MainActivity from the main

```
package com.example.miraapp;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{


Button button1;
EditText etResponse;
    TextView tvIsConnected;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this); 


}

private void button1Click()
{
    startActivity(new Intent(this,GUI.class));  
}
public void onClick(View v)
{

    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button1:
            button1Click();
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            button2Click();
            break;
    }
}

private void button2Click()
{


}

};
```

here is my manifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.miraapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
 >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"

 />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.miraapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.miraapp.GUI"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

here is my fragment_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context="com.example.miraapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="131dp"
    android:text="@string/START_fix" 
    android:onClick="button1Click"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/title_fix"
    android:src="@drawable/mira4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
    android:text="@string/CONNECT_fix" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So... where is your code?

Comment: Please post the `onCreate` method for `MainActivity`, along with any other relevant parts of the code. And point out which is line 30 of `MainActivity.java`.

Comment: post the relevant layout xml also

Comment: Without any code given how can the code be corrected???

Comment: Your buttons in fragment_main.xml while you're setting the content from activity_main.xml. Tha's why NPE. Move your buttons to activity_main.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button belongs to the `fragment_main.xml` not `activity_main.xml`. Hence the initialization of buttons fails leading to `NullPointerExcpetion`.

Either initialize the button in `onCreateView` of `Fragment`. I don't see a `fragment` in your code.

So just change this

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please correct this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

your layout name is fragment_main

Answer (score 0):

Copy the whole code in `fragment_main` to `activity_main`..

Or

change this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main)
```

Thats the solution to the problem..